# Swift how to compare string which come from NSString

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, compare

I get a return number(0 for success, 1 for failure) form sever made by php
so I want get this number to judge my operation succeeded or not.
I use this :

```
var str1 :String = NSString(data: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let str2 = "1"
println(str1) // output is 1
println(str2) // output is 1

if(str1==str2){println("same")} //but the two is not same
```

so I debug for this and I get this result:
//str1  _countAndFlags  UWord   13835058055282163717    -4611686018427387899
//str2  _countAndFlags  UWord   1   1

And I try to use toInt. I get 1383... form str3 and 1 form str4
 So how can I do to solve this problem.
 Thank you very much.

Comment: If Swift says the strings are unequal, then they are unequal. Beware of whitespace and non-printable characters.

Comment: I would say this is the likely problem (to check quickly, change your `println(str1)` to `println(",".join(map(str1,toString)))` – if you see any commas, that’s your problem).  However you seem to have 4 variables in play here – `str3`, `str4`, `returnOne` and `str1`.  You’re comparing `returnOne==str1`, but assigning values to `str3` and `str4`...

Comment: sorry I compare str3 and str4 they are not same

Comment: I got ,,,,1 in your way.But how to solve this, thank you.

Comment: I dont understand what is str3 and str4? you are just comparing str1 and returnOne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have some whitespace in your string.  To spot this using `println`, you could try `println(",".join(map(str1,toString)))`.  If you see any commas at all, that's the problem.

The easiest way to fix this (it may be better to kill the whitespace at the source) is to use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`:

```
let str1: String = NSString(data: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                   ?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(
                     NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
let str2 = "1"
if str1==str2 { println("same") }
```

Note a few other changes:

- `let` rather than `var` since it doesn't look like you need to change `str1` after it's declared
- No force-unwrap (`!`) at the end of the creation of the `NSString`.  Never force-unwrap something that might be nil, you will get a runtime error!
- `?.` to optionally call the trim if it isn't nil.

Note, this means `str1` is a `String?` not a `String` but that's fine since you can compare optionals with non-optionals (they'll be equal if the optional contains a value equal to the non-optional, but not if the optional contains `nil`)

If what you actually want is an `Int`, just add a `let int1 = str1?.toInt()`.  This will still be an optional – if there is a reasonable default in case of `nil`, you could do `let int1 = str1?.toInt() ?? 0` and it will be non-optional with a value of `0` in case of `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

in swift 2 you can use 
`let str = "string"
let nsstr:NSString = "string"
if nsstr.containsString(str){
print(true)
}else{
print(false)
}`

it works for me