# How to compare upper and lowercase letters in a conditional in Swift

Tags: string, swift

Apologies if this is a duplicate. I have a helper function called inputString() that takes user input and returns a String. I want to proceed based on whether an upper or lowercase character was entered. Here is my code:

```
 print("What do you want to do today? Enter 'D' for Deposit or 'W' for Withdrawl.")

    operation = inputString()

    if  operation == "D" || operation == "d" {

        print("Enter the amount to deposit.")
```

My program quits after the first print function, but gives no compiler errors. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried using some breakpoints? What does the `inputString()` method look like?

Comment: func inputString() -> String {
    
    let keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData
    
    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
}

Comment: when I call print right after assigning the results of inputString to operation, I get the entered value, so I know it's being assigned. I feel like I'm missing something obvious about Strings in Swift.

Comment: @jdlace Hi, it might be helpful for other readers if you put the `inputString` function (as you have in the comments) in your original post.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to keep in mind that there is [a whole slew of purely whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18169122/2792531) that show up in strings, and sometimes, those whitespace characters can lead to problems just like this.

So, whenever you are certain that two strings should be equal, it can be useful to print them with some sort of non-whitespace character on either end of them.

For example:

```
print("Your input was <\(operation)>")
```

That should print the user input with angle brackets on either side of the input.

And if you stick that line into your program, you'll see it prints something like this:

```
Your input was <D
>
```

So it turns out that your `inputString()` method is capturing the newline character (`\n`) that the user presses to submit their input.  You should improve your `inputString()` method to go ahead and trim that newline character before returning its value.

---

I feel it's really important to mention here that your `inputString` method is really clunky and requires importing modules.  But there's a way simpler pure Swift approach: `readLine()`.

Swift's `readLine()` method does exactly what your `inputString()` method is supposed to be doing, and by default, it strips the newline character off the end for you (there's an optional parameter you can pass to prevent the method from stripping the newline).

My version of your code looks like this:

```
func fetchInput(prompt: String? = nil) -> String? {
    if let prompt = prompt {
        print(prompt, terminator: "")
    }
    return readLine()
}

if let input = fetchInput("Enter some input: ") {
    if input == "X" {
        print("it matches X")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nhgrif. I was hoping to find a pure Swift solution that didn't involve other classes. Gotta read up on readline(). Thanks, again.

Comment: `readLine()` is pretty straightforward.  It reads from standard input to the next newline character or EOF, which ever comes first, and returns that as an optional string `String?`.  It does basically exactly what your `inputString()` method is attempting to do, only better, and pure Swift.

Answer (score -1):

the cause of the error that you experienced is explained at [Swift how to compare string which come from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27800513/3839235). Essentially, we need to remove any whitespace or non-printing characters such as newline etc.

I also used .uppercaseString to simplify the comparison

the amended code is as follows:

```
func inputString() -> String {
    var keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    var inputData = keyboard.availableData
    let str: String = (NSString(data: inputData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(
    NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()))!
    return str
}

print("What do you want to do today? Enter 'D' for Deposit or 'W' for Withdrawl.")

let operation = inputString()

if operation.uppercaseString == "D"  {
    print("Enter the amount to deposit.")
}
```

Comment: The code snippet it resolves the problem.  The plain English ignores the actual problem.

Comment: i had posted up a link which explained the cause of the problem, so as to give credit to the poster.